# Tag synonym request: [xcode-ide] -> [xcode]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are two tags [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) and [xcode-ide](/questions/tagged/xcode-ide) on SO. I suggest to make [xcode-ide](/questions/tagged/xcode-ide) a synonym for [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode).

---

There are also a lot of another **xcode** tags such as [xcode3.2](/questions/tagged/xcode3.2), [xcode3.2.3](/questions/tagged/xcode3.2.3), [xcode4.2](/questions/tagged/xcode4.2), e.g. Some of them are very rarely used, but I not sure that all of them should have the same synonym.

Comment: I just added [xcode-ide] as a synonym for [xcode], so people can vote on it now: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/synonyms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 that [xcode-ide](/questions/tagged/xcode-ide) should be made a synonym of [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode).

I don't think all of the versions should be synonymized, because Xcode can change substantially between major versions.  Witness, for example, the difference between Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.  Even Xcode 4.2 is different from 4.1 because of the iOS 5-specific things that were added (support for Storyboards, for example).

*However*, tags like [xcode3.2.3](/questions/tagged/xcode3.2.3) aren't very worthwhile, and I'd recommend that we only have tags for the major feature releases: [xcode4](/questions/tagged/xcode4), [xcode4.1](/questions/tagged/xcode4.1), [xcode4.2](/questions/tagged/xcode4.2), etc.  Minor versions such as [xcode3.2.3](/questions/tagged/xcode3.2.3) should be collapsed into their parent version tag of [xcode3.2](/questions/tagged/xcode3.2).